# How to initialize variables in an LSTM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm having difficulty when I try to run this LSTM model in TensorFlow. I'm relatively new to the library, so forgive me.

```
from tensorflow.contrib import ffmpeg, rnn
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import time

# hyperparameters
learning_rate = 0.01
total_iterations = 100
layer_width = 5
network_depth = 10

# path variables
mp3_output_path = "/Users/espresso/Documents/Projects/Martin/ouput"
mp3_input_path = "/Users/espresso/Documents/Projects/Martin/input/Caravan.mp3"

# Function Definitions
def import_audio(mp3_location):
    binary_audio = tf.read_file(mp3_location)
    audio_tensor = ffmpeg.decode_audio(binary_audio, file_format="mp3", samples_per_second=int(44100/2), channel_count=1)
    reformatted_audio_tensor = tf.reshape(audio_tensor, [1, tf.shape(audio_tensor)[0], 1])
    return reformatted_audio_tensor


def export_audio(audio_tensor, mp3_target_dest):
    encoded_audio = ffmpeg.encode_audio(audio_tensor, file_format="mp3", samples_per_second=(44100/2))
    mus_file = open(mp3_target_dest, 'wb+')
    mus_file.write(encoded_audio)
    mus_file.close()
    print("Export complete. File located at {}".format(mp3_target_dest))
    return 0


def lstm_layer(cell_quantity):
    return rnn.LSTMCell(cell_quantity)


def stacked_lstm(layer_width, depth):
    if type(layer_width) == list:
        lstm_layer_lib = [lstm_layer(layer_width[element]) for element in layer_width]
    else:
        lstm_layer_lib = [lstm_layer(layer_width) for element in range(depth)]
        lstm_layer_lib.insert(0, lstm_layer(3))
        lstm_layer_lib.append(lstm_layer(1))

    return rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layer_lib)

def inaccuracy(net_loss):
    return net_loss

# variable definitions
input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 5282816, 1], name="Audio_Input")
y_labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 5282816, 1], name="Y_Labels")

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

network_outline = stacked_lstm(layer_width, network_depth)
hypothesis, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(network_outline, input, dtype=tf.float32)
cross_entropy =   tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_labels, logits=hypothesis))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    input_mp3_tensor = sess.run(import_audio(mp3_input_path))
    vector_size = int(sess.run(tf.shape(input_mp3_tensor))[1]) - 1


    y_labels_tensor = sess.run(tf.convert_to_tensor([input_mp3_tensor[0][element+1][0] for element in range(vector_size)] + [0]))
    reformatted_y_labels_tensor = sess.run(tf.reshape(y_labels_tensor, [1, tf.shape(y_labels_tensor)[0], 1]))

    for iteration in range(total_iterations):
        loss, _ = sess.run([cross_entropy, optimizer], feed_dict={input: input_mp3_tensor, y_labels: reformatted_y_labels_tensor})
```

As you can see, I have declared tf.global_variables_intilizer() in the variable init_op and I execute it before executing any another operation in the Session.  Still, once the code completes, the following error message is returned:

```
Caused by op 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_4/lstm_cell/bias/read', defined at:
  File "martin.py", line 41, in <module>
hypothesis, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(network_outline, input, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 635, in dynamic_rnn
dtype=dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 832, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 3202, in while_loop
result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2940, in BuildLoop
pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2877, in _BuildLoop
body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 3178, in <lambda>
body = lambda i, lv: (i + 1, orig_body(*lv))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 803, in _time_step
(output, new_state) = call_cell()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 789, in <lambda>
call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 191, in __call__
return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 714, in __call__
outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1242, in call
cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 298, in __call__
*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 696, in __call__
self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 730, in build
initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer(dtype=self.dtype))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 546, in add_variable
partitioner=partitioner)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable.py", line 415, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
**kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1297, in get_variable
constraint=constraint)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1093, in get_variable
constraint=constraint)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 431, in get_variable
return custom_getter(**custom_getter_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 194, in _rnn_get_variable
variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 408, in _true_getter
use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 800, in _get_single_variable
use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2157, in variable
use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2147, in <lambda>
previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2130, in default_variable_creator
constraint=constraint)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 235, in __init__
constraint=constraint)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 388, in _init_from_args
self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 142, in identity
return gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3053, in identity
"Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3290, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1654, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_4/lstm_cell/bias
 [[Node: rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_4/lstm_cell/bias/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_4/lstm_cell/bias)]]
```

I'm not entirely sure if I'm actually supposed to create weights and pass them into TensorFlow functions as a parameter. But I have no other idea as to why the program is unsuccessful.

Comment: Would you mind adding the missing code so your example will be runnable?

Comment: Just updated it:)

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. I'd deleted init_op. Everything should be fine now.

Comment: I should inform you that there are two variables: mp3_input_path, and mp3_output_path that need to be changed to suit the locations of an mp3 file on your computer. The variables are located in line 13 and line 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error is that you defined the `init_op` before defining your variables (i.e. before calling `stacked_lstm` and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`. This means that the variables you defined after having called `init_op`  won't be initialised.

You should do something like:

```
network_outline = stacked_lstm(layer_width, network_depth)
hypothesis, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(network_outline, input, dtype=tf.float32)
cross_entropy =   tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_labels, logits=hypothesis))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I must declare the operation itself after I declare any other operations that create any variables. Thanks!